# Design a transition diagram for Finite Automata that accepts a language L over Σ {0,1} in which every string start with 0 and ends with 1

Tags: computer-science, finite-automata, state-machine

What's the transition diagram of this Finite Automata? Is the diagram shown in the image correct?

Comment: Sounds like you want us to do your (home?)work for you. That's not really what we're here for.

Answer (score 0):

it's a very basic automata !

It can be completed with a "Trash" state if needed ...
Coresponding regex is : 0(0|1)*1

[image: FSA]